# c# read attribute value

Tags: c#

ich have a xml file with the following structure:

```
<layer1 name="this is layer1">
  <messages>
    <message name ="com_request">0</message>
    <message name="send">1</message>
    <message name="request">2</message>
  </messages>
</layer1>
```

I try to collect all the message names in one indexer using the code:

```
SampleCollection<string> paramCollection = new SampleCollection<string>();

string pathxml = @"C:\myXML.xml";
int j=0;

XmlTextReader xmlin = new XmlTextReader(pathxml);
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = xmldoc.ReadNode(xmlin);

foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
{
   paramCollection[j] = item.Attributes["message name"].Value;
   Console.WriteLine(paramCollection[j]);
   j++;
}
```

However it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what others have mentioned (attribute name is wrong), also your node points to `layers1`, who only has the direct child `messages`, so there are no `message` nodes in your child collection. The same thing in LINQ is trivial - switch if you can:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("message"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("name").Value);
}
```

Comment: although i add using system.xml.linq.xdocument, the xdocument is underlined with red squiggle.

Comment: @JohnMunich: you should only need `using System.Xml.Linq;` for this to work

Answer (score 3):

The name of your attribute is `name`, not `message name` (`message` is the name of the node).

If you can describe more clearly what you're trying to do, I (or someone else) can provide a more specific solution.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name is **not** `message name`, it is `name`

```
foreach (XmlNode item in node.ChildNodes)
{
   paramCollection[j] = item.Attributes["name"].Value;
   Console.WriteLine(paramCollection[j]);
   j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

XmlNodeList list = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/layer1/messages/message");
List<string> messageNames = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode node in list)
{
   messageNames.Add(node.Attributes["name"].Value);    
}
```

This should extract all `<message>` nodes using XPath, and then grab their `@name` attribute into a list of strings.

Comment: could you give me any example about xpath?

Answer (score 1):

Your node selection is wrong. Its needs to be more like:

```
string pathxml = @"C:\myXML.xml";
int j=0;

XmlTextReader xmlin = new XmlTextReader(pathxml);
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = xmldoc.ReadNode(xmlin);

foreach (XmlNode item in xmldoc.SelectNodes("layer1/messages/message"))
{
    paramCollection[j] = item.Attributes["name"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(paramCollection[j]);
    j++;
}
```

So you get a collection of message nodes for the foreach to iterate over. Then the attribute is simple referenced as 'name'

Comment: its strange, it still doesn't work. Because of the comments:`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
`

Comment: Can I see an example of the whole file please?

Comment: I have just spotted an issue with my code adjustment. Change xmldoc.SelectNodes("layer1/messages/message") to node.SelectNodes("messages/message")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linq to XML

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"d:\temp\myXml.xml");
var msgnames = from q in doc.Descendants("message")
               select q.Attribute("name").Value; 

foreach(string item in msgnames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as other have pointed out, **your attribute is called `name`**.

As for your task to collect some values in XML tree, you could have used XPath language to query the document. This would enable you to **avoid writing boilerplate code that traverses the tree, as well as easily adapt to XML structure changes**:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (xs);

var attrs = doc.SelectNodes ("/layer1/messages/message/@name");
var values = attrs.Cast<XmlAttribute> ()
    .Select (a => a.Value);
```

However, since I already used LINQ to cast nodes into attribute instances, **it makes sense to use LINQ to XML instead, which was designed for querying XML from C# code**:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse (xs);
var values = from msg in doc.Descendants ("message")
             select msg.Attribute ("name").Value;

Console.WriteLine (values);
```

Both of these options are good and depend on what framework you plan to use for working with XML, System.Xml or LINQ to XML. For new code, I suggest using LINQ.

In both cases, you need a simple `foreach` loop to enumerate values:

```
foreach (string value in values)
    Console.WriteLine (value);
```

Comment: how to retrieve the value in the values?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. `values` in both cases is of type `IEnumerable<string>`, meaning you can go through them in a `foreach` loop: `foreach (string value in values)`. If you need a `List<string>` or `string []` array, call `ToList` or `ToArray` on `values`.